# How to properly return in component fetched data as array from utils using TS and Next13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to figure out what is the most correct way to type responses from an external API using TypeScript.

In my example I want to fetch data and foreach value I want to render a component with specific prop that comes from resposne.

This is my fetchPopularMovies function that is stored in seperate file in utils.

fetchPopularMovies.ts

```
interface Movie {
  id: number;
  poster_path: string;
}

interface PopularMoviesResponse {
  results: Movie[];
}

export async function fetchPopularMovies(): Promise<PopularMoviesResponse> {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?language=en-US&page=1",
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.BEARER_TOKEN}`,
      },
    }
  );

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch popular movies");
  }
  const responseData: PopularMoviesResponse = await response.json();
  return responseData;
}
```

Here is my current implementation in Page.tsx

Page.tsx

```
export default async function Home() {
  const data = await fetchPopularMovies();

  return (
    <>
      <main className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="flex">
          <aside className="flex flex-col gap-3 p-10 flex-[0_0_10%]">
            <p>Movies</p>
            <p>TV Shows</p>
            <p>Channels</p>
            <p>Others</p>
          </aside>

          <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-6 p-10 align-center justify-center grow">
            {data.results.map((movie) => (
              <>
                <MovieTail key={movie.id}>
                  {/* @ts-expect-error Async Server Component */}
                  <ImageComponent posterUrl={movie.poster_path} />
                </MovieTail>
              </>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is this how it should look like in TS?
Can you guys do some kind of code review or give me an another example?

I've tried this code and everything works fine, I'm just thinking is that a good approach.

Comment: you should use redux and meddleware for asyncronous fetching and  call your fetchPopulermovies() inside useEffect hook